# How to click the Li element in Selenium by javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium, navigationbar

I wonder how we can click the item inside the li element in selenium script by javascript. There is a few ways i had tried but it could solve my problem, like By.cssSelector or by css. but the error given is always ElementClickInterceptedError: element click intercepted:Other 
element would receive the click or like element is not clickable at point

I would like to click on the second li in the html, but inside that html has few item.

I wonder why it keep saying that other element would receive the click? I have choose the a href correctly, but it keep saying the statement above. May I know is there any other reasons that causing that to be happened?

Html

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
  <li class="nav-item"></li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="aaa" href="abc">
     <span>
      <fa-icon></fa-icon>
      <span jhitranslate="a.b.c"></span>
     </span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I have tried this, but it gives me timeouterror

```
async function clickDashBoard() {
    let aa =
        await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css("navbar-nav li:nth-child(2).nav-item")), 10000);        
        await aa.click();
}
```

full xpath: /html/body/jhi-main/div[1]/jhi-navbar/nav/div/ul/li[2]/a/span/span

Can anyone can help me on this? Thank you.

Comment: Try with following `css` selector :  `let aa =await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css(".navbar-nav li:nth-child(2)>a")), 10000); `

Comment: @KunduK i tried your answer, it return me this Element <a ...">...</a> is not clickable at point (589, 41). Other element would receive the click: <div class="modal-header">...</div> I wonder why it would said the element is not clickable?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this out since I don't know where you are trying this out. But maybe the below works.

```
        //Find element, I am assuming the a element is the one to click

        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ul.navbar-nav > li.nav-item > a"));
        JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

        //Use JS to click on element

        jsExecutor.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", element);

        //or if that does not work, use dispatch a mouse event.

        jsExecutor.executeScript(
                "var rect = arguments[0].getBoundingClientRect();" +
                          "arguments[0].dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {" +
                          " 'view': window," +
                          " 'bubbles': true," +
                          " 'cancelable': true," +
                          " 'clientX': rect.left + rect.width/2," +
                          " 'clientY': rect.top + rect.height/2" +
                          "}))"
                , element);
```